# How do I write to a memory mapped file using a writeExternal (Externalizable interface) method?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, objectoutputstream, externalizable

I hava a memory mapped file where I can write values as follows:

```java
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){

        try {
            // OPEN MAPPED MEMORY FILE
            file = new RandomAccessFile("myMemoryMappedFile", "rw");

            // ASSIGN BUFFER
            fileBuffer = file.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024);

            // INITIALIZE ALL FILE TO 1
            for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
            {
                fileBuffer.put((byte) 1);
            }

            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.writeExternal(???????);    // HOW DO I LINK THE fileBuffer and the ObjectOutput?

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error while opening a new database: file not found.");
            return false;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error while opening a new database: IO exception.");
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

And I have a class which implements `Externalizable` which overrides `writeExternal` method:

```
public class MyClass implements Externalizable {

    public long epochBegin = -1;
    public long epochEnd = -1;
    public int data = -1;

    public MyClass(){
    };    

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {

        byte[] epochBeginByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt((int)this.epochBegin).array();
        byte[] epochEndByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt((int)this.epochEnd).array();
        byte[] dataByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt((int)this.data).array();

        out.write(epochBeginByte);
        out.write(epochEndByte);
        out.write(dataByte);

        out.flush();

    }

}
```

I would like to invoke the method `writeExternal` over the memory mapped file `myMemoryMappedFile` at position 10 bytes. So in the file, at byte 10 there will be 12 bytes containing the variables `this.epochBegin`, `this.epochEnd` and `data`.

Unfortunatelly I am totally stuck on how to link both things, the memory mapped file and the `writeExternal` procedure. Any tip on how to continue is welcomed.

Comment: You need to put a `ByteArrayOutputStream` under the `ObjectOutputStream`, do the writes, close, get the byte array, and put that to the `MappedByteBuffer`. As you can see there is no advantage to using mapped I/O in this situation: it is in fact slower and wastes memory.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit this? How do I put a `ByteArrayOutputStream` under the `ObjectOutputStream`?. The mapped I/O is required as it is used as IPC mechanism (the included code is just a simplified replicable example).